# Error list <dynamic> ' is not a subtype of type 'string' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am using nodejs and mongodb as the backend I have created model classes but when I am trying to display the Json data its showing error I am not able to solve the error list  ' is not a subtype of type 'string' in type cast

I am getting the json data from the backend
[my json data and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/553WP.png)

addproductmodel class

```
    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'addproductmodel.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Addproductmodel {
  String username;
  String product_name;
  String product_details;
  String productImage;
  String quantity;
  String currency;
  String unit;
  @JsonKey(name: "_id")
  String id;
  String mrp;
  String sp;
  String per;

  Addproductmodel(
      {
        this.username,
        this.product_name,
        this.product_details,
        this.productImage,
        this.currency,
        this.quantity,
        this.unit,
        this.id,
        this.mrp,
        this.sp,
        this.per,

      });

  factory Addproductmodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AddproductmodelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AddproductmodelToJson(this);
}
```

supermodel class

```
import 'package:flutter_app/Model/addproductmodel.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'supermodel.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class SuperModel {
  List<Addproductmodel> data;
  SuperModel({this.data});
  factory SuperModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SuperModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SuperModelToJson(this);
}
```

main function screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Model/addproductmodel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Model/supermodel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/NetworkHandler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Product/AddProduct.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Product/products.dart';

class ProductScreenTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductScreenTestState createState() => _ProductScreenTestState();
}

class _ProductScreenTestState extends State<ProductScreenTest> {

  NetworkHandler networkHandler = NetworkHandler();
  SuperModel listModel = SuperModel();
  List<Addproductmodel> cart= List<Addproductmodel>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData1();
  }
  void fetchData1() async {
    var response = await networkHandler.get("/add_product/getproducts");
    setState(() {
      listModel=SuperModel.fromJson(response);
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
      Container(
        child: listModel.data.length == null ? Center(
          child: Text("We don't have any Products Yet"),
        ) : ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index)=>
            dataShow(listModel.data[index]),
          itemCount: listModel.data.length == null ? 0 : listModel.data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget dataShow(Addproductmodel obj){
    return
      Container(
        height: 40,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 15, 8),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Text(
          "${obj.product_name}",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: `productImage` in your JSON is a `List<String>` and not `String` as your model specifies.

Comment: i am using other ways to retrieve the image

Comment: help me in solving the problem

Comment: Your model handles the parsing of the JSON in the generated method `_$AddproductmodelFromJson`. Since your JSON is not compatible with your model, this parsing will fail which is also indicated by the error. You need to fix your model so it is compatible with the JSON you want to parse.

Comment: what kind of fix

Comment: i am using json annotation and json serializable to generate .g.dart files

Comment: Try change `String productImage;` to `List<String> productImage;`.